# How to execute a command with a button and delete it before the command ends ? Python / Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've got an interface where there is a 'Start' button. It runs a 'main' command where it starts a loop to run some measurements on a powermeter. I want to be able to click on an 'OK' button every time the measure is ready to be done. This button would replace the 'Start' button.

But when I try to destroy the button (`buttonStart.destroy()`) and then run the command `main()`
, the command executes but doesn't delete the button until the very end.
I've tried using threads from threading package, but it doesn't really work.

If there is a way to both destroy the button and run a command, I would be very interested !

Thanks a lot

Comment: The button is destroyed but `main()` blocks tkinter from updating.  You can add `root.update()` (assume `root` is the root window) after `buttonStart.destroy()` to force tkinter to update.  However, better way is to use thread if `main()` is a time consuming task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event loop must be given the opportunity to process events in order for the window to be removed from the screen.

There are a couple of ways to make that happen. The first is to call the `update_idletasks` method on any widget. That is usually enough to process the event related to the destruction of the widget, though it may be necessary to call `update` instead. Calling `update` should be avoided if at all possible. My rule of thumb is to start with `update_idletasks`. If that doesn't work, switch to `update` or switch to using `after`.

```
def my_custom_function():
    startButton.destroy()
    root.upddate_idletasks()
    main()
```

The second method is to run your `main` function via `after` or `after_idle`. This will let tkinter naturally process all pending events before starting `main`. I would argue that this is the best approach. I recommend trying `after_idle` first, and if that doesn't work, switch to `after` with a small delay.

```
def my_custom_function():
    startButton.destroy()
    root.after_idle(main)
```